# Need some help in downloading pics from a website

Tags: php, .net, scripting

I am looking for some help in downloading pics from a website. Here is the problem detail.

URL is basvandenbroek dot com, 
suppose when we visit the following page http://www.basvandenbroek.com/nl/product/27341/704/snaarinstrumenten/boston/snarenset_elektrisch.html

we have a thumbnail pic here which when click bring its larger version. I would like to capture the larger image using a php script and download it onto my pc.

Problem is when we inspect the HTML we see the following code for images

```
../../../../../../../jpg/27000/27341.jpg
../../../../../../../jpg/cache/27000/220_220_27341.jpg
```

Based on the above code i assume that if i append website address at the start of the 
`jpg/27000/27341.jpg` I could access the pic but its not working it that.

I believe URL is hidden or I might not understanding things properly. I am new to PHP and Scripting and I would like somebody to help me through it situation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

relative urls are relative to the url of the containing document.  so if the document you're scraping is located at http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/doc.html, and the image is referenced as
../../omg/wtf/lol/cat.jpeg, its full url is http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/../../omg/wtf/lol/cat.jpeg, or http://example.com/foo/omg/wtf/lol/cat.jpeg.

btw, this has nothing to do with PHP or scripting in general, and is instead firmly a HTTP thing.  and there are no "hidden" URLs in HTTP, that would be a contradiction.

edit: your comment makes it look like the problem is with the Referer header or session id sent (or not) in your request.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. There are around 16000 total products listed in this website. I completely understand that if I use http://www.basvandenbroek.com/jpg/27000/27341.jpg I could access the image of the product I have listed on my original post. Now, issue is like 27341.jpg there is another product pic 27342.jpg is present which is associated with another product. If i try to access that by  changing url like http://www.basvandenbroek.com/jpg/27000/27342.jpg, it would return me a error page, where as product pic is there on the server.

Answer (score 0):

For the website you mentioned, if the thumbnail is

```
http://www.basvandenbroek.com/jpg/cache/27000/220_220_27341.jpg
```

then the

```
http://www.basvandenbroek.com/jpg/27000/27341.jpg
```

So the thumbnail is basically the dimensions (220 x 220) added as a prefix to the original in a different folder. Also, there is nothing like hidden URL. Any link that is valid on a web-page is sure to appear in the source of the html. In chrome and firefox, atleat, you can find this link by right-clicking the link and copying the link address.

In your case you can find the thumbnail's url by right-clicking the thumbnail and  the original's url by right-clicking it.

However, if you want to do this automatically using PHP, you will have to write code that can parse the html for the page to determine the urls.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, here would be the larger image: 
http://www.basvandenbroek.com/jpg/27000/27341.jpg
The smaller image is at:
http://www.basvandenbroek.com/jpg/cache/27000/220_220_27341.jpg

This means you would need to scrape out the first two underscored parts of the name (220_220) using string manipulation. You would also want to string replace "cache/" with an empty string.